# Proof that every subset of a discrete space is open and closed (visualizing 'Accumulation Points' definition)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I know this question is a duplicate, but I want to understand it in terms of accumulation points and internal points, etc.

**QUESTION**

Let X be any set and $d : X \times X \to \mathbf{R}$ be given by $$ d(x,y) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x = y$} \\
1, & \text{if $x \neq y$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Prove that every subset of $X$ is both open and closed.

**REMARKS**

First of all the definition I like to use of 'closed' is the following:

> Let $E$ be a set of real numbers. The set $E$ is said to be closed provided that every *accumulation point* of $E$ belongs to the set $E$
>
> Accumulation point: Any point $x \in R$ (not necessarily in $E$) provided that for every $c>0$ the intersection $(x-c,x+c)\cap E$ contains infinitely many points.
>
> *Thomson, Bruckner, Bruckner Elementary Real Analysis, 2nd Edition (2008)*

I began to visualise the subsets and exactly what they would look like.

I considered case 1 - where $d(x,y) = 0 for x=y$

I imagined this would be a group of subsets that looked like this:

$(..., [x_{i-2}], [x_{i-1}], [x_{i}], [x_{i+1}],...)$

Basically, sets of single values. Now, I begin to think of accumulation points. And how I could work that into this particular situation.

I thought of a literal example. Let's look at a interval $[x_i - c, x_i + c]$ This point would only intersect with our $E$ (in this case the set $[x_i]$) when $c=o$. So then how can we say this set is one that contains infinitely points and satisfies our definition?

Am I right in thinking that this set only has one accumulation point? And is that all I need to do to say that this set is closed?

Or am I just looking at all of this the wrong way?

Comment: The approach utilising the definition of openness in metric spaces may be a little bit more straightforward. Since
$$B_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \{x\} \qquad \forall x\in X$$
All one-point sets are trivially open. All subsets are unions of those and so on...
For the closedness you can WLOG (_why?_) assume you sequence is the constant sequence and there you go...

Comment: What is WLOG? @AlexR

Comment: "without loss of generality"

Answer (score 3):

Here are the definitions that will give you the answers relatively quickly:

> **Definition (opennes)**
>   Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset X$. Then $A$ is open iff
>   $$\forall a \in A\quad \exists \delta > 0: \ B_\delta (a) := \{x\in X: d(x,a) < \delta\} \subset A$$

and

> **Definition (closedness)**
>   Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset A$ with $$\lim_{n\to\infty} d(a_n,a) = 0$$
>   If this implies $a\in A$, then $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you were taking $[x_i - c, x_i + c]$ from the book to be your open ball of radius $c$ about $x_i$, and this is with respect to the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, which is $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. However, your metric is different, so if you take a ball of any radius about $x$ *with respect to your weird metric*, you will see what AlexR is talking about.

In any case, the point is: The book reference has a particular metric in mind when defining accumulation point. You need a general one that works for all metric spaces.